# Hibernate mapping with ID generated by DB trigger + sequence

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, triggers, sequence

everyone.
I've a LOG table with a combination of trigger and sequence to create the id, so when I insert the line I do not have to specify the id, otherwise the database returns error. However Hibernate claims (rightly) that was specified primary key.

**What kind of "generator" property should I use in this case?**

I already tried "**assigned**" it says:

```
org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save (): it.m2sc.simulator.beans.Log
```

With "**select**" hib ask me the natural key, but there is no natural key in this table, but the primary.

```
org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: no natural-id property defined; need to specify [key] in generator parameters
```

That's my hbm

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="it.m2sc.simulator.beans.Log" table="LOG">
        <id name="id" type="integer" column="LOG_ID" access="field">
            <generator class="select" /> 
        </id>
        <property name="date" type="date" column="LOG_DATE" access="field" />
        <property name="user" type="string" column="LOG_USER" access="field" />
        <property name="evtId" type="integer" column="EVT_ID" access="field" />
        <property name="detail" type="string" column="LOG_DETAIL" access="field" />
        <property name="deleted" type="character" column="LOG_DELETED" access="field" />
        <property name="codiceRaggruppamento" column="LOG_CODICE_RAGGRUPPAMENTO" type="string" access="field" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The Class

```
public class Log {
    private Integer id;
    private Date date;
    private String user;
    private Integer evtId;
    private String detail;
    private Character deleted = '0';
    private String codiceRaggruppamento;

    ... ( getter & setter )
}
```

DDL of table/trigger/sequence

```
CREATE TABLE
    LOG
    (
        LOG_ID NUMBER(12) NOT NULL,
        LOG_DATE TIMESTAMP(6),
        LOG_USER VARCHAR2(50),
        EVT_ID NUMBER(12),
        LOG_DETAIL VARCHAR2(100),
        LOG_DELETED CHAR(1) DEFAULT '0 ' NOT NULL,
        LOG_CODICE_RAGGRUPPAMENTO NCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT LOG_PK PRIMARY KEY (LOG_ID),
        CONSTRAINT LOG_CFG_EVENT_TYPE_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (EVT_ID)
        REFERENCES CFG_EVENT_TYPE (EVT_ID)
    );

   CREATE SEQUENCE  LOG_SEQ  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 358 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "DTCUSR"."LOG_TRG" BEFORE INSERT ON LOG
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  <<COLUMN_SEQUENCES>>
  BEGIN
    IF :NEW.LOG_ID IS NULL THEN
      SELECT LOG_SEQ.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.LOG_ID FROM DUAL;
    END IF;
  END COLUMN_SEQUENCES;
END;
```

Ah, just fyi: db is Oracle11

Ty in advice

Comment: Tried with "**native**" too, it says: 'select hibernate_sequence.nextval from dual' :(

Comment: Have you found any solution? I'm facing the same problem and I cannot use the sequence value generation in oracle. I need to use a trigger.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the goal you need to use GenerationType.IDENTITY

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "LOG_ID", updatable = false, nullable = false)
private Integer id;
```

See more on https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-generate-primary-keys/

Comment: that used to work for me too. after I upgraded my ojdbc.jar, it got messed up

Comment: GenerationType.IDENTITY creates "generated as identity" (in Oracle) and this does not allow you to enter the ID manually (and thus use the trigger) as required in the question.

Answer (score 0):

`sequence-identity` id generation strategy embeds sequence call directly in the insert statement:

```
insert into log (log_id, log_date, log_user, ...)
values (LOG_SEQ.nextval, ?, ?, ...)
```

This way you can get rid of the trigger because it's not needed.

Also, you have to set `hibernate.jdbc.use_get_generated_keys` property to `true`, so that Hibernate reads the generated keys after executing insert statements.

In hbm.xml:

```
<id name="id" type="integer" column="LOG_ID" access="field">
  <generator class="sequence-identity" >
    <param name="sequence">LOG_SEQ</param>
  </generator>
</id>
```

With annotations:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "LOG")
public class Log {
  @Id
  @org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator(name="logSequenceGenerator", strategy = "sequence-identity",
    parameters = {@org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name="sequence", value="LOG_SEQ")})
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "logSequenceGenerator")
  @Column(name = "LOG_ID")
  private Integer id;
  ...
}
```

Comment: the problem is that I can't rid of the trigger, this DB is made by another co-worker and I have to work with what I have

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [link](http://developer-should-know.com/post/82479486933/how-to-use-oracle-before-insert-trigger-for-id) explaining how to use a trigger based generator.

Additionaly, remember to use the hibernate.jdbc.use_get_generated_keys property in your Hibernate persistence configuration

```
<property name="hibernate.jdbc.use_get_generated_keys" value="true" />
```

Probably you will get an NullPointerException while inserting using the class described on the link. Change the method executeAndExtract(PreparedStatement insert, SessionImplementor session) to anything like this

```
    @Override
    protected Serializable executeAndExtract(PreparedStatement insert, SessionImplementor session)  throws SQLException {

        insert.executeUpdate();

        try {

            ResultSet rs = insert.getGeneratedKeys();
            rs.next();

            return rs.getLong(1);

        } catch (RuntimeException rt) {
            throw new SQLException("Error while attempt to use the CustomTriggerGenerator. Check the <property name=\"hibernate.jdbc.use_get_generated_keys\" value=\"true\" /> in your persistence.xml");      
        }

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Hibernate doc is really clear on different generation mechanism available. Depending on how data will be written one should make a call:

For simple use cases you might use `sequence`, but there are several more options available.

Refer: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id

Comment: I read that refer, because it is referenced by other topics here on StackOverflow, but unfortunately I have not found the answer to my question. I wrote this post very detailed to find additional help.

Answer (score -1):

If you want your ID to be generated only in database and just read by hibernate you can use parameters 'insertable' and 'updatable' in [@Column](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Column.html) annotation:

```
@Column(name = "LOG_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
private Integer id;
```

With this parameters hibernate will not add the id column to inserts and updates.

Comment: Wrong. With @Id this doesn't work. I've got ``@Id @Column(name = "ADH_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
 private Long id;`` and still get the exception: ``org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned beforeQuery calling save()``